# Leave Approval Status in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, I want to display leave application status that can be either apply, approve, reject or cancel.

If all leave approve then status = approve, like other leaves

but if there are mix status e.g some leave approve , some rejected then status = Partial.

I have written the code but I feel it is complicated, can I get it in one, single query?

```
create table #t
(
    employeeID int,
    LeaveCode nvarchar(10),
    status nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #t 
values(1, 'PL', 'Approve'), (1, 'PL', 'Reject'), (1, 'PL', 'Approve')

;with ct1 as 
(
    select status, count(status) Cnt 
    from #t 
    group by status
),
counters as
(
    select count(*) as TotalLeave 
    from #t
)
select top(1)
    CASE
       WHEN C1.Cnt = C2.TotalLeave 
          THEN C1.status  
       ELSE 'Partial' 
    END [status]
from 
    ct1 C1 
cross join 
    counters C2

drop table #t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
create table #t
(
 employeeID int,
 LeaveCode nvarchar(10),
 status nvarchar(50)
)
insert into #t values(1,'PL','Approve'),(1,'PL','Reject'),(1,'PL','Approve')
insert into #t values(2,'PL','Approve'),(2,'PL','Approve'),(2,'PL','Approve')

SELECT 
    employeeID,
    CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT status) = 1 THEN MAX(status) ELSE 'Partail' END [status]
FROM #t
GROUP BY employeeID

drop table #t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t.status) > 1 THEN 'Partial'
        ELSE MAX(t.status)
    END OveralLeaveStatus
FROM #t t
```

Answer (score 1):

simply group by employee and check for max(status) <> min(status), if it is difference than it means at least one the status is different

```
select  employeeID,
        [status]    = case  when min([status]) <> max([status]) then 'Partial'
                else min([status])
                end
from    #t 
group by employeeID
```